# Code for factorials in objective C

Tags: objective-c, factorial

Using only for or while statements, I'm trying to come up with a program to generate and print a table of the first 10 factorials. Here's my code:

```
    for (count = 1; count<=10; ++count) 
    {
        n = count;
        while (n > 0){
            count *= (count-1);
            n -= 1;
        }
        NSLog(@"  %2g            %3g", count, factorial);
    }
```

I don't understand why this is not working. It never gets out of the loop and goes on forever. What's the correction? Thank you!

Comment: Side note: use tabulations (character *'\t'*) instead of writing all that spaces manually.

Answer (score 4):

The reason:

```
count *= (count-1);
```

Since `count` starts at 1, it will always be reset to `0`, so the `count <= 10` condition of the outer loop will always be true, hence the infinite looping.

And you're overcomplicating it anyway.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int r = 1, n = i;
    while (n)
        r *= n--;

    printf("%d! = %d\n", i, r);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Math, n! is the same thing as Γ(n+1) (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

So just use:

```
-(float)factorial:(float)number1 {
    return tgammaf(++number1);
}
```

> **This will even work for floats and negative numbers,**
>
> **other solutions posted are long and extraneous and only work with
>   positive integers.**

Comment: Do you need to use `++number1` instead, so that `number1` is incremented **before** being passed to `tgammaf`?

Comment: @user2194039 I will admit I'm not yet an "expert" in objective-c but I dont think that's how objective-c works. I've never heard of ++num, BUT, I am almost certain that num++ will be processed BEFORE tgammaf

Comment: `++num` is different than `num++`, and this is common to many programming languages, including C and family. `++num` increments `num` _before_ returning it. 'num++' increments `num` _after_ returning it. In your function, you want `tgammaf(num + 1)`, which is to say `num` must be incremented _before_ `tgammaf` gets it. Using `num++` increments `num` only _after_ `tgammaf` gets it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) shows that C and family support both `++num` and `num++`.

Comment: From a [different page on increment and decrement Unary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators): "_the pre-increment and pre-decrement operators increment (or decrement) their operand by 1, and the value of the expression is the resulting incremented (or decremented) value. In contrast, the post-increment and post-decrement operators increase (or decrease) the value of their operand by 1, but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment (or decrement) operation._"

Comment: In any case, I only commented because I found your code very useful, but happened across that one small bug in testing. So +1 from me!

Comment: So odd! I tested it on my end too and it worked just fine with num++, were you using objective-c?

Comment: try printing both number++ and ++number with NSLog()

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Indeed, in Objective-C. I literally copy-pasted your function into a project and tested it. I just did it again in a fresh project. You should test it again. Running `NSLog(@"%f", [self factorial:4.0]);` yields `6`, not `24`. You get six because the function is really calculating `3!`, then incrementing `number1`. And I'm sorry for bugging you about this, but I really do think you have the best answer for this question, and I like how you've solved it by looking at it as a math problem and using built-in math functions. It just needs one small change to be 100% correct!

Comment: @user2194039 You're right! Wow, I must have had +1 in my code and when I came over here i changed it to ++, I'll fix it now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

During the first loop iteration *count* is 1 and so also *n* is 1, then you enter the while and you set *count* to zero (*count-1*), and decrease *n* which becomes zero and you exit the while. So during the second loop iteration *count* will be zero. You keep decreasing *count* and it never gets increased, so you never exit the loop until a numeric overflow occurs.

You're doing it harder that what it is (and also inefficient) . Is enough that you keep multiplying *n* for *count* to get the factorial:

```
int n=1;
for (count = 1; count<=10; ++count) 
{
    n*= count;
    NSLog(@"%d",n);
}
```